# Text dissapears when image is loaded from picasso - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a recycler view which loads an image and a text. When the image is loaded from the url though picasso other elements is the recycler view loose their text. The elements who loose their text they dont load their image from www but from android drawable folder. All the images are the same size and i tried it with the same image and it still happens. If you could provide any insights because i dont know what to do or try.


Here is a gif of my problem: https://giphy.com/gifs/hR5w7IrCZ14T9M8o7A

--- Edit ----
Tried the answer from Radesh didnt work. Tried glide instead of picasso (seems glide to be much faster). The problem seems to be the way recycler updates. 

My onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    myViewHolder.textItem.setText(categoryItem.get(i).getEng_name());
    if (categoryItem.get(i).getDefault_image().equals("empty") || categoryItem.get(i).getDefault_image().length() == 0) {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.no_image).into(myViewHolder.image);
    } else {
        Glide.with(myViewHolder.context).load("https://i.ibb.co/wwT602t/lake-plastira.jpg").into(myViewHolder.image);
        //Picasso.get().load("https://i.ibb.co/wwT602t/lake-plastira.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image).error(R.drawable.failed_to_load).into(myViewHolder.image);
    }
}
```

My xml for the items loaded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview_id"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/color4">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:textColor="?attr/color6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My recyclerView code

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.categories_rec);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mAdapter = new SpecificCategoryAdapter(categoryItem);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Pasting your code (inline) is more preferable than adding several external links.

Comment: I dont like to clutter the page for no reason. But i will try it though next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I find a solution I used a runnable and the problem was solved. If you have any other idea please post it. I believe that this behaviour happened because that function never ended because it was waiting for the image.

```
 myViewHolder.textItem.setText(categoryItem.get(i).getEng_name());
  if (categoryItem.get(i).getDefault_image().equals("empty") || categoryItem.get(i).getDefault_image().length() == 0) {
      Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.no_image).into(myViewHolder.image);       
  } else {
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              Glide.with(myViewHolder.context).load("https://i.ibb.co/wwT602t/lake-plastira.jpg").into(myViewHolder.image);
          }
      };
      handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

change this code

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:textColor="?attr/color6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To this

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:textColor="?attr/color6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately the behaviour is the same. I dont understand why it looses the text.